# WSDL Parsing error - Error: Failed to parse wsdl: attribute name can not be null at: 32:54

Tags: apex, wsdl, wsdl2apex

```
<xsd:attribute name="Type" type="xsd:anyURI"/>
```

I checked a few forums and it was mentions

1.The WSDL maybe using the rpc/encoded interaction style, this is not supported by the Salesforce WSDL2Apex tool. You'll have to manually create/parse requests to this API.

2. Change name attributes to  simpleTypes

Can anybody suggest any workaround/provide links ?

Comment: Error says: attribute name can not be null at: 32:54, Try adding name to the node at line number 32. Salesforce expects specific parameters for nodes.

Comment: @RahulSharma  This is my line 32 . Can you please let me know what exactly I need to put ?   <xsd:attribute name="Type" type="xsd:anyURI"/>

Comment: <xsd:attribute name="Type" type="xsd:anyURI" name="Salesforce"/>, Something like this. Give it a name and see, you might additional errors with it, so keep modifying the WSDL until its parsed.

Comment: @RahulSharma - Is there any alternative way to your syntax ? Because it's giving error "Found invalid XML. duplicated attributes :name and :name "

Comment: sorry I didn't noticed that type is already present.

Comment: what if you change the type to xsd:anySimpleType or xsd:String?

Comment: I am currently stuck at  this error -- Unsupported Schema element found http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:attributeGroup . Can anyone suggest a workaround?

Comment: @Vanilla_Sky please share the complete WSDL. I've got an [alternative](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) (free) version of Wsdl2Apex that can often work around problems like this.

Comment: @DanielBallinger - Thanks but I have organizational restrictions on usage of any external converter. Is there any other way out?

Comment: @Vanilla_Sky If you could share the WSDL it will be much easier to isolate the problem or problems. I could run it through the tool to see what modifications are required. change the endpoint url first if you don't want to expose where it is hosted.